# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

i have this error while i want to create dynamic navigation with multiple pages..
here is code below..

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screens/locations/locations.dart';
import 'screens/location_detail.dart';

 const LocationsRoute = "/";
 const LocationDetailRout = '/location_detail';

 class App extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
    onGenerateRoute: _routes(),
);
```

}

```
 RouteFactory _routes() {
   return (settings) {
   // final Map<String, dynamic> arguments = settings.arguments;
    final arguments = settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
    Widget screen;
    switch (settings.name) {
      case LocationsRoute:
      screen = Locations();
      break;
      case LocationDetailRout:
      screen = LocationDetail(arguments['id']);
  }
};
```

}

}

Answer (score 4):

Quick fix

```
Map arguments = (settings.arguments??{}) as Map;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to flutter official documentation at
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments
The onGenerateRoute() function creates the correct route based on the given RouteSettings.

So the thing that we have been doing wrong was that **we were looking for arguments for every route in the main block (outside of switch statements)**, but only **LocationDetailRoute** route has the **arguments** that's why we were getting null for all other routes.

```
RouteFactory _routes() {
    return (settings) {
      Widget screen;
      switch (settings.name) {
        case LocationsRoute:
          screen = Locations();
          break;
        case LocationDetailRoute:
          // Correct Place for this Statement
          final arguments = settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>; 
          screen = LocationDetails(arguments['id']);
          break;
        default:
          return null;
      }
      // return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => screen);
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => screen, settings: settings);
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [arguments](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteSettings/arguments.html) of `RouteSettings` can be `Null` and this is why you are seeing the error  here `final arguments = settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;` . You are basically trying to cast `Null` to a `Map`. Also i am not sure if this is intentional, but your inner function (the actual `RouteFactory`) is not returning a `Route` in any case.

Comment: then how should i fixed it

Comment: You should probably only extract the arguments if you expect the route to have arguments. Or just check if arguments are Null before extracting (although this would crash further down when you try to access arguments)